# Find centroids of polyline and create point using Arcobject

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, vb.net

I have one road feature class and one area feature class .What i have to do is i have to create a point at the centroids of the polylines of (road feature class) and find intersection of point with the area boundary.

How can i get the centroids of polylines in arcobject through vb.net code and create point with that (x,y) and then find intersection with area boundary????

Comment: A centroid does not exist for a polyline feature. It exists only for polygon features.  Can you explain what exactly you need? Additionally, can you add your ArcGIS version and license level?

Comment: Centroids do exist for polylines also.

Comment: A more common term is midpoint.

Comment: @GISGe: Can you share some reference which defines and explains what a centroid of a line is?

Comment: Centroid (or midpoint or whatever you call it) is a property of the polyline geometry object, check http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Polyline/018z00000008000000/. You can try the Feature to Point tool, it will also work with lines.

Comment: A centroid and a midpoint are **not** the same thing. The midpoint of a line or polyline is the point on the line equidistant from both ends. The centroid of a line or polyline is the geometric center of the region (minimum bounding area) of that line. With a line (two point) the midpoint and the centroid are the same, but typically with a polyline the centroid will not fall on the line itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ArcInfo licence, you can get polyline centroids using the feature vertices to points tool (select MID as your point location). You can execute this tool in your .net code using geoprocessing.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003p000000

How to execute geoprocessing tools in .net:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003rr000000

To get the intersection points of geometry objects, it's best to use iTopologicalOperator.Intersect:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003vs000000

Answer (score 1):

You can get the polyline midpoint from a selected line feature using this general logic:

```
        Dim mxdoc As IMxDocument
        Dim app As IApplication
        Dim hook As Object

        app = CType(hook, IApplication)
        mxdoc = CType(My.ArcMap.Application.Document, IMxDocument)

        Dim pMap As IMap
        Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
        Dim pFeaturelayer2 As IFeatureLayer2
        Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection
        Dim pSelectionSet As ISelectionSet
        Dim pFeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor
        Dim pFeature As IFeature
        Dim pGeometry As IGeometry
        Dim pPolyline As IPolyline
        Dim pPoint As IPoint
        Dim Xmid As Double, Ymid As Double

        pMap = mxdoc.FocusMap

        pMap = mxdoc.ActiveView.FocusMap
        Dim pEnumLayer As IEnumLayer = pMap.Layers

        Dim pLayer As ILayer = pEnumLayer.Next
        Do Until pLayer Is Nothing
            If pLayer.Name = "Your Line Layer Name" Then
                pFeatureLayer = pLayer

            End If
            pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next
        Loop

        pFeaturelayer2 = pFeatureLayer
        If pFeaturelayer2.ShapeType <> 3 Then
            MsgBox("The layer must be a polyline")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        pFeatureSelection = pFeatureLayer
        pSelectionSet = pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet
        If pSelectionSet.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No feature selected")
            Exit Sub
        End If

            pSelectionSet.Search(Nothing, False, pFeatureCursor)
            pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
            pGeometry = pFeature.ShapeCopy
            pPolyline = pGeometry
            Dim pPoint As IPoint

            pPolyline.QueryPoint(esriSegmentExtension.esriNoExtension, 0.5, False, pPoint)
            Xmid = pPoint.X
            Ymid = pPoint.Y
            MsgBox("Point on the polyline X,Y=" & Xmid & "," & Ymid)
```

Then, you may reference this Q/A for creating the point.

[How to create a graphic point by xy value?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19201/how-to-create-a-graphic-point-by-xy-value)

Comment: Your code needs two fixes, first, you have to intialize the pPoint to a new point since QueryPoint will generate an error. And second, you have to set the ratio parameter to True for the 0.5 so it takes 50% of the distance.. Your code currently goes 0.5 units of measurements.